# Using a Return URL Securely

Tags: mysql, api, returnurl

Hopefully this question isn't too naive...

I'm attempting to implement [The Giving Lab API](http://www.thegivinglab.org/platform/#donation) in order to allow users of my site to donate to charity.

> Using a URL such a this:
>
> https://www.thegivinglab.org/api/donation/start?donationtype=0&amount=10&charityid=84ed3c54-6d8c-41c5-8090-f8ec800f45a7&returnurl=mywebsite.com/
>
> the user is directed to the donation page and then returned to the returnURL after the donation has been made.

I want to be able to add how much the user donated to my databases if they successfully complete a payment. Would it be possible to use the returnURL to do this? Ie could I use a returnURL in the form of mywebsite.com?q="amount_donated" and then use this to update my databases?

I can see that this would allow someone to update my databases by just entering the returnURL into their browser.

Is there a generally better method, that removes this problem?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dutch banks use a thing called a sha-sign (and they're probally not the first)

All you have to do is add a key which only you can know:

```
function makeSecureCode($var1, $var2){
    $secretCode = 'example';
    $secretKey = '';
    $secretKey.= $var1 .  $secretCode;
    $secretKey.= $var2 .  $secretCode;

    return sha1($secretKey);
}
```

Then make the url like this: ?var1=foo&var2=bar&key=5e8b73da0b20481c1b4a285fb756958e4faa7ff1

And when you process the code after payment, makeSecureCode( $_GET['var1'], $_GET['var2']) should be equal to $_GET['key']. If not, someone changed it.

This is a simplefied version with only two vars. You can make it have more input arguments, or an array, whichever you prefer.